# Reportviewer authentication when IIS is on a different server

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

Folk, finding it hard to find information for this particular scenario.

IIS is on one server and the developers are using Forms authentication in ASP.NET 4.5 with the AD as the membership provider.

Reportserver is SS2016 Standard is running as a domain account and has the following authentication types:

`<AuthenticationTypes>
    <RSWindowsNTLM/>
    <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
</AuthenticationTypes>`

If the developer has `<identity impersonate="true" />` we get "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized" and no account listed. Without the impersonate we get rsAccessDenied with the service account of IIS listed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed all the steps listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Answer (score 0):

What do your logs say? Check your report logs (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512029.aspx) as well as Event logs on the report server.

Does the impersonated user have database/data source permissions?

If, after reviewing your logs you can't figure it out, please post them here.